# "removeHeader is not a function" error on restart NextJS project Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, next.js

I have the problem on Next.js project. I'm run the project on live-server, doing all [by this instruction](https://www.coderrocketfuel.com/article/how-to-deploy-a-next-js-website-to-a-digital-ocean-server). In first runnig by command `npm run start` all correct, but if i restart the server i have next error:

```
TypeError: a.removeHeader is not a function
    at SendStream.removeContentHeaderFields (/home/dzi/website/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/send/index.js:1:5160)
    at SendStream.notModified (/home/dzi/website/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/send/index.js:1:5273)
    at SendStream.send (/home/dzi/website/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/send/index.js:1:7976)
    at onstat (/home/dzi/website/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/send/index.js:1:8914)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:184:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nexjs-format-app@0.0.1 start: `next start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nexjs-format-app@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

If i run project with pm2, i have the same error. Log file of pm2:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle nexjs-format-app@0.0.1~prestart: nexjs-format-app@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle nexjs-format-app@0.0.1~start: nexjs-format-app@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle nexjs-format-app@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle nexjs-format-app@0.0.1~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/dzi/website/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local>
9 verbose lifecycle nexjs-format-app@0.0.1~start: CWD: /home/dzi/website
10 silly lifecycle nexjs-format-app@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '-c', 'next start' ]
11 silly lifecycle nexjs-format-app@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle nexjs-format-app@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: nexjs-format-app@0.0.1 start: `next start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid nexjs-format-app@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd /home/dzi/website
16 verbose Linux 5.4.0-26-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.15.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error nexjs-format-app@0.0.1 start: `next start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the nexjs-format-app@0.0.1 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Help me plz. My config files:

```
[package.json]
{
  "name": "nexjs-format-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Online market",
  "main": "_app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "market",
    "format"
  ],
  "author": "Dz",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "firebase": "^8.0.1",
    "next": "^10.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  }
}
```

```
[next.config.js]
module.exports = {
    trailingSlash: true,
    distDir: 'build'
  }
```

Server: Ubuntu 20.04 x64, 1 core, 1GB RAM

Comment: Hey! Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Could be related to images, see this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/19309#issuecomment-874402983